# In SharePoint filterable tables, how do I delete an existing table and import a CSV file's data that has the same columns?

Tags: csv, sharepoint, import, grid

I have an existing, filterable list / table in SharePoint.
This table needs to be entirely updated with data from a CSV file which has the same columns.
I don't see an "import" option, the way you see it in Excel. What is the equivalent?

The behavior of the Edit Grid was counter-intuitive, e.g. didn't seem to have bulk-import functionality.